# GCP: IP address restriction to use service account from limited set of ip addresses

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, openvpn, google-cloud-networking

I am using service accounts to access GCP resources like compute engine api , data store api  . Is there any way to add ip restriction so that I can use service account only from some particular set of  ip addresses ?
As of now if I have service account credential for some GCP resource then I can access these resources from anywhere using service account , I want to restrict it to only a set of ips .

Comment: It would be helpful to comment before down voting .  What ever research I have done regarding this topic I have found aws provide ip restriction for IAM policies  . I wanted to know is it also possible in GCP as I could not find it in google documentation .

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Service Account credentials cannot be restricted by location of the user, IP address, etc. Once you grant permissions to the credentials, they can be used from anywhere on any device that has access to Google Cloud.

AWS does provide some IAM policies that can be applied to some services (S3) based upon IP address. Google Cloud does not offer an equivalent feature yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is a capability called VPC Service Controls which can allow specific projects,  IP Ranges and Service Accounts to have access to Google APIs in a protected project.

I'm not 100% sure if your specific use case can be configured, but look at the example here describing the "On Premise Network" example:

https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/private-connectivity#on-premises_network_example

you'll need to learn about [Access Levels](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-access-level) and [how to attach them to a VPC SC Perimeter](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/use-access-levels)

but what you're looking to do seems quite possible with an IP Address-based access Level and a perimeter around the project.

Answer (score 1):

The Google APIs are not project resources. To restrict access to a set of IPs would not be limited to just your project. IAM permissions are how access is controlled rather than IP based restrictions.

You can't restrict access to the APIs based on the requestor IP, only through IAM permissions

Comment: the problem is that the google api are accessible on internet, and if you whant use only private cloud network you cannot protect the access of the api. but i think that vpc sc permit to bloc access from internet...

Comment: Even using VPC SC only applies within your projects. It does not stop API calls coming from the internet. And the API itself will authenticate with whatever credentials it receives. I know this functionality can be implemented if GCP added conditional permissions, but that needs to be a feature request